# convert java to ruby

Tags: java, ruby

I have java sample code

```
public int[] recognize(int[] x)
{
    int[] y = new int[neurons.length];

    for (int j = 0; j < neurons.length; j++) {
        y[j] = neurons[j].transfer(x);
    }

    return y;
}
```

I need to convert it into ruby

Comment: [Learn Ruby](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/tutorial.html)

Comment: I can convert all, but "int[] y = new int[neurons.length];" - i cann't

Comment: [This might help](http://punerb.blogspot.in/2006/06/arrays-in-ruby.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ruby, higher order functions are preferred over explicit loops.

```
def recognize(x)
  neurons.collect {|n| n.transfer(x)}
end
```

Comment: yes but I like leaving out the (), it feels more 'ruby'. Also map instead of collect for the true ruby experience.

Comment: @pguardiario, `map` are `collect` are the same, aren't they?

Comment: Yes but map is more common and therefore more 'ruby', at least IMHO

Answer (score 3):

```
def recognize x #returns all transfer results 
  y=neurons.collect{|n|n.transfer x}
  y
end
```

Comment: just a small remark, actually y var is not needed here as ruby returns the result of last line evaluation

Comment: i know. i just wanted to give him his y variable and to point out that y is returned.